# gdal_retile.py syntax error issue

Tags: python, gdal

I am trying to use gdal_retile.py to retile a very large (19gb) raster. The dimensions are approx 2000 x 27000 pixels.

This is what the code looks like:

```
gdal_retile.py -targetDir /home/user/folder/folder/test_folder test_file.img -ps 5000 5000
```

The test file is in the test folder. I'm getting invalid syntax errors in the test file, but when I send the -targetDir to the back, I get invalid syntax errors for the first 5000 of the pixel size command.

I am a beginner at python and have never used it with GDAL before. Also, I am using a Linux remote desktop, so perhaps there is an issue with the file path. I copied directly from "location" in the file explorer.

Comment: The name of the parameter "pixelsize" is misleading. If I understand right it could rather be "tilesize". At least I think that with the default value 256 x 256 means that images get split into tiles of that size. You use tile size 5000 by 5000 that is wired than the input image. Use smaller -ps value or leave it out if you want to have a try with the default size.

Comment: @user30184 thanks for the tip, unfortunately changing the size doesn't seem to make a difference. I've tried a range of numbers from 20 to 5000 and always receive an invalid syntax error

Comment: You are trying to run a command-line tool from a python interpreter.  Run it from a terminal instead.

Comment: @user2856 thank you for this! i will try it out immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a test with this procedure:

Create a 2000 by 27000 pixel test image with gdal_create

```
gdal_create -of GTiff -co tiled=yes -co compress=deflate -outsize 2000 27000 retile.tif
```

Run gdal_retile

```
gdal_retile -targetDir test_folder retile.tif
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

So no errors at all. I used GDAL and Python tools from OSGeo4W. No problem with bigger tiles either with command

```
gdal_retile -targetDir test_folder2 retile.tif -ps 1000 1000
```

Comment: I realized my problem was that I was trying to run it from a python interpreter, so when I switched to the terminal it worked fine. Thank you for running the test for me! I am wondering if you had any issues with the output tiles being rotated ~90 degrees?

Comment: No I hadn't. Feels like some projection problem. What is the coordinate system of your source image?

Comment: It's transverse mercator. I think it's somehow flipping the x and y axes, but I'm not seeing a way to specify them in the gdal_retile documentation.